# How to avoid repeated executions of the same event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router, gantt-chart

The events of my component work well until I do the following:

1. Change of screen by clicking on a menu of options and through the
   router access to another component.
2. I go back to my original
   component.

When i do that, my component's events duplicated.
So, for example, the handleAddTask event is executed as many times as clicks have done on other menu options.
If I do not fire any routing to another module, then the events work well and do not duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event listeners that are attached on componentDidMount do not disappear when the component is unmounted, so i get a new set of listeners each time you re-mount the component.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `click` events like

```
<div onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)} ... >
```

Use binding in `constructor`

```
constructor() {
  this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
}
```

---

In `onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}` this click will be bind each time render refreshes

Instead of binding the event in render function bind it in `contructor`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sadly, I'm not using that kind of events, at least, not in the "react" part of the components I use. In this component i do use the bind in the constructors. Maybe in the internal libraries of the component there are such things. If there were any way to eliminate the events that are stacked ...

Comment: @Cognitiva, is there any way that I can check your code,or please share the code block that is causing the issue

Comment: Many thanks Vivek, i have found the problem: Event listeners that are attached on componentDidMount do not disappear when the component is unmounted, so i get a new set of listeners each time you re-mount the component.